# What is velocity in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, velocity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I've always thought that velocity is the quantity $\vec v=\frac {d \vec x} {dt}$ by definition. That is, velocity is a quantity whose measurement is the above operation of the quantities $\vec x$ and $t$.

Then I studied quantum mechanics and I've seen the indetermination principle:it is impossible to know position and momentum $P$ simultaneously.

Taking $P=m \vec v$ as the definition of momentum involves that velocity can't be the quantity $\vec v=\frac {d \vec x} {dt}$ by definition, because it would violate the indetermination principle, indeed:

1. To know velocity I need to know $x(t)$ and $x(t+dt)$ that means I know the position.
2. Moreover, imagine to have a system (whose position is undetermined), if the above definition of velocity is correct than when we measure velocity the result would be infinite, because $x(t)$ can be completely different respect to $x(t+dt)$

So, what is the definition of velocity?

Comment: Since you cannot measure $x(t)$ and $x(t+\mathrm{d}t)$ for truly infinitesimal $\mathrm{d}t$ and so you cannot *really* compute instantaneous velocity from position measurements, I don't see where your problem with the operator equation $p = m\dot{x}$ in the Heisenberg picture is (for system where the canonical momentum $p$ really is $m\dot{x}$ classically).

Comment: To measure velocity I need to measure $x(t)$ and $x(t+ \Delta t)$. Then the limit $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ gives velocity. The impossibility of this measurement is that in practice we can't measure in $dt$. Anyway, assuming  that we can measure position in a $\Delta t$ that is small respect to the typical times of our system we can say we have velocity ad time $t$. So we have both position and velocity

Comment: Imagine to have a system (whose position is undetermined), if the above definition of velocity is correct you probably measure infinite all the times, because $x(t)$ can be completely different respect to $x(t+dt)$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to compute time derivatives in QM is in the Heisenberg picture.
We know that for any operator $\hat{A}$ the Heisenberg equation of motion holds:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \hat{A} = \frac{1}{i\hbar} [\hat{A},\hat{H}] + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \hat{A}$$
More specifically for the position operator, the partial derivative will be zero, giving us
$$\frac{d}{dt} \hat{x} = \frac{1}{i\hbar} [\hat{x},\hat{H}]$$
and, considering an Hamiltonian of the type $\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(\hat x)$, this further simplifies to
$$\frac{d}{dt} \hat{x} = \frac{1}{i\hbar} \left[\hat{x},\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}\right]$$
because $V(\hat x)$ commutes with $\hat{x}$.
Using the commutation relation $[\hat{x},\hat{p}^2] = 2 i \hbar \hat{p}$ we obtain
$$\frac{d}{dt} \hat{x} = \frac{\hat{p}}{m}$$
Which is consistent with the classical view that $p = m \dot{x}$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} \hat{x} = \frac{\hat{p}}{m}$ is a relation between the form of the position operator and the time operator. It means that, the operator of the observable velocity and the operator of the observable position are related in that way. But what is the observable velocity? namely, how do you measure velocity?

Comment: The operators *are* the observables. The result of a measurement will be simply taking the expectation value of the operator on a specific state. Nothing changes in the equation: $\frac{d}{dt} \langle \hat{x} \rangle = \frac{\langle \hat{p} \rangle}{m}$.

Comment: Observables are quantities that can be measured, operator are mathematical objects that correctly interpreted gives us the proprieties of the quantity they represent. For example $\hat T = \hat X + \hat P$ is an Hermitian operator, which quantity  it represents?

Comment: The QM understanding is that observables are operators whose eigenvalues provide the possible outcomes of the measurement process. It is true that not all Hermitian operators are observables, but only because not all infinite-dimensional Hermitian operators are diagonalisable. Whether or not the operator corresponds to a physical quantity that you are familiar with or can devise an experiment for is not relevant.

If your question is about how to *experimentally* measure the velocity of a particle, you should rephrase it.

Comment: Ok, so how do you measure velocity?

Comment: Of a particle? Experimentally? Usually by measuring the deflection radius in a magnetic field, obtaining the momentum through $p = qrB$ and dividing by the mass.

Comment: “The QM understanding is that observables are operators whose eigenvalues provide the possible outcomes of the measurement process” In your definition there is the measurement process, so to define what is an observable you need to know which quantity you are measuring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110585/discussion-between-simobartz-and-lvdt).